# Display different image for different url

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styling

I have a WordPress Woocommerce e-shop.

In every product category, I want this to have a different top image.

The Woocommerce category pages are automatically created so I can't edit them individually.

I have managed to find a way to have my own image on top but I want this image to be different for different categories.

So I thought that if I could handle the images displayed inside this by referring to their URL this would solve the problem.
So let's say for URL

```
example.com/category/category1
```

display image-1 and so on.

Something like a CSS selector

```
div[this-url-1] {background-image:url(.image-1..);}
div[this-ur2] {background-image:url(.image-2..);}
```

Comment: You should be able to access the categories in Woocomerce and add an image there regardless if they're created automatically?

Comment: the way woocommerce places the images in the category layout doesn't fit my design, so ideally i would like to change the contents of a specific div i have access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plug in to do what you want.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-category-banner/

This will allow you to use custom images and positions of images for each category.

Comment: this looks great, i am going to give it a try and let you know

Comment: Hope it helps :). When in doubt with wordpress, use a plugin hehe